# Javascript get array element from the condition of summation of array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array, arr = [2,4,8,7,3,6] I want to make each element of it be summation when the result is 10 , then save the element it would be arranged to another array.

make the element that result is 10 close each other like 2 and 8, add to another element named arr2.

result i need : arr2[2,8,3,7,4,6]

my code :

```
const arr = [2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6];
let arr2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
  let Number1 = arr[i];
  let Number2 = arr[(i + 1)];

  if (Number1 + Number2 === 10) {
    let element1 = arr.indexOf(Number1);
    let element2 = arr.indexOf(Number2);
    arr2.push(element1, element2);
  }

  console.log(arr2[i]);
}
```

someone can solve my problem please ?

Comment: Wouldn't your `arr2` be `[8,6,2,3,7,4]`?

Comment: @sm3sher From what I understand you need to re-arrange the elements so each pair sums to 10. The expected result `[2,8,3,7,4,6]` can be explained if you read it like this: `[(2,8),(3,7),(4,6)]` Like you can see the elements are re-arranged to form pairs that have a sum of 10. I'm not quite sure if there is any logic behind the order of the pairs. It looks like OP wants `(low,high)` then the next pair is `(low,high)` again, but the new `low` is higher than the previous value.

Comment: OP, can we assume that the provided input can always form a valid result? If not, what should happen if no valid result can be created? For example with the input `[7,8,1,2]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create `arr2` so that the items sum up to 10 you can make use of a simple `map` here:

```js
const arr = [2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6];

const arr2 = arr.map((item) => 10 - item)

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first loop through the array to create a dictionary of value to index, then loop the array again and lookup for the complement of the current value to the target. If it exist then yes you got the answer.

`.filter(x => x > i)` is to search for complement that has higher index than current one so that we will not get duplicated result pushed. For example input is [2, 8], you don't want to get [2, 8, 8, 2]

[Here is my solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gJgDQwCy4AcuA7LgMy4BsAugNwBQANgKayIKaob0MMBmAVzDAoAS3AwIIJoPHgAFFEQBzNgC4YYQQFsARiwS4xYAA5zN2-YfQ0AlJd0GEtmAG8GMLzFCRYCFghBJihHaxcabltGbx9waBgmEBAAawBVUwBZOFNNN3QUlgBPMOcaUpsaAF9uNyrGT29WWDFuAAYY734QZAVfBJY4YAALGBB+GBNzKDt3RtivMQmFAEIFQZHJsETk9Kycu1mPBZOd1Izs03QN4ci0aPmFqr5Ts73L66HbgDpzCGGFGI7A1XmIANRgzpeZ6PVpoDqPbq9fqwG5jCZTORHR6xFEwAAmS34hhYIhY3GUCDUsAAtDAbiDTksYApCfxiQEyVs3hcDnNXrj4rBQDpTKwdKSoABJMD4lgAD24SXO+yubI5pOALBo334YhChgUipQAD4YIqzUD0G1eALvDimcsRWKWBKwNLZQrsXaTgEgiFfoJ-oCzHJ0GIaMZQ1B0M7xZKZXL5fYoQLnq8YaCIanM94AlBBAhtn7glBGDCOFw0NJZPIwAoAIxtXAcYF8foyFjfJIqBSV4FAA)

```
const arr = [2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6];
let arr2 = [];

function solution(target: number, input: number[]): number[] {
    const result: number[] = [];
    const lookUpMap: {[key: number]: number[]} = {};

    let i = 0;
    for (const each of input) {
        if (!(each in lookUpMap)) {
            lookUpMap[each] = [];
        }

        lookUpMap[each].push(i);

        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    for (const each of input) {
        const difference = target - each;

        if (difference in lookUpMap) {
            const complementIndex = lookUpMap[difference].filter(x => x > i)[0];
            
            if (complementIndex) {
                result.push(input[i], input[complimentingIndex]);
            }
        }

        i++;
    }

    return result;
}

arr2 = solution(10, arr);

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming a valid result can be created for the given `arr`.** A fairly simple solution would be to sort the array first. Then step through half the array and take the element on the current index, and the element on the inverse index (`length - 1 - index`). And `push()` those both in the resulting array.

So here in steps, given you have the following array:

```
[2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6]
```

You sort it:

```
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Then you step through half the indexes and take each element, and the element on the inverse index.

```
   [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
//   \  \  \/  /  /  
//    \  ------  /    -> [2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6]
//     ----------
```

```js
const arr = [2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6];

const sortedArr = Array.from(arr).sort((a, b) => a - b); // ascending
const length    = sortedArr.length;
const nPairs    = length / 2;

const arr2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < nPairs; ++i) {
  arr2.push(
    sortedArr[i],
    sortedArr[length - 1 - i],
  );
}

// or if you want a more functional approach:
// const arr2 = Array.from({ length: nPairs }).flatMap((_, i) => [sortedArr[i], sortedArr[length - 1 - i]]);

console.log(arr2);
```

Do note that this is probably not the fastest solution, because sorting is non-linear.

Obviously this solution does not work if an invalid input is given, like `[7,2,1,8]` which can never produce a valid output.